# Scala: Declaring method with generic type parameter

Tags: scala, generics

What is the equivalent of the following Java method declaration in Scala:

```
public <T>  T readValue(java.lang.String s, java.lang.Class<T> tClass)
```

In other words, I'd like to declare a method that takes a class of type T, and returns an instance of that type.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

- I. Very close to what you want:

  ```
  def readValue[T:ClassTag](s:String):T = {
    val tClass = implicitly[ClassTag[T]].runtimeClass
    //implementation for different classes.
  }
  ```

  usage is a bit clearer than in Java:

  ```
  val myDouble = readValue[Double]("1.0")
  ```

Comment: You are welcome. When you had implemented the method and looked at the answer II., you'd find it more extensible and modular.

Comment: @Neil, `ClassTag`s are the idiomatic way to do this in Scala, but you can pass `Class` objects directly as you'd do in Java: `def readValue[T](s: String, cls: Class[T]): T` - definition, `readValue("1.0", classOf[Double])` - usage. This is not idiomatic, but sometimes can be helpful.

Comment: Also there is [`TypeTag`](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html) class which is part of 2.10 reflection library. It allows you to get even generic type parameters, something which is not possible to do in Java (at least, without hacks).

Answer (score 2):

- II. Another, more involved way, is to externalize implementation of readValue to some user-provided object (type class):

  ```
  trait ValueReader[T] {
    def readValue(s: String): T
  }

  def readValue[T: ValueReader](s: String): T = {
    val reader = implicitly[ValueReader[T]]
    reader.readValue(s)
  }

  implicit val doubleReader = new ValueReader[Double] {
    def readValue(s:String) = // implementation for Double
  }
  ```